# How does Typescript restrict subclass in generic function?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to create a function which could only accept generic types which were subclass of a centain base class and reject all the other types such as:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C {}

function foo<T extends A> () : T {
  return undefined
}

foo<B>()
foo<C>()   // <- I'd like the compiler throw out an error on this line
```

How can I make the `foo<C>()` fail in compilation?

Comment: You can't `return undefined` in `foo` function!

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Don't mind that's a example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you believe me if I told you `C` actually *is* a subtype of `A`? Typescript is structurally typed, so any object that implements a given interface for `A` is considered a valid value of type `A`. Since `A`'s interface is `{}` (i.e. no interface at all), any Javascript object is an value of type `A`.

If the interfaces don't match, then the subclass check will fail.

```
class A {foo() {}}
class B extends A {}
class C {}
```

Now `C` is not a subtype of `A`. If you want to be absolutely sure, you can make a private field. Private fields are never compared structurally, so a private field on `A` can only ever be present in actual subclasses of `A`.

```
class A {private _placeholder: null = null}
class B extends A {}
class C {}
```

There's a distinction between *subclassing* and *subtyping* here. In some languages like Java, the two are similar enough that you can treat them as interchangeable in many situations, but not so in Typescript. In your first code example, `B` is a subclass of `A` (because it *subclasses* it with the `extends` keyword, or moreover because `A` appears in the prototype chain for instances of `B`). However, `C` and `B` are both subtypes of `A` (since instances of either can safely be substituted anywhere a value of type `A` is expected). In general, every subclass relationship defines a subtype relationship, but not every subtype relationship is defined by a subclass relationship.

This is also true of union and intersection types. It's completely accurate to say that `string` is a subtype of `number | string`, since a `string` can always be safely treated as a `number | string`, but it's not accurate to say that `string` is a subclass of `number | string` (not least of all since neither of the things mentioned is a class).

Comment: Does that mean the generic subsitution is based on `subtype` instead of `subclass`?